# nx dep-graph not showing any relations

Tags: angular, nestjs

I have this Angular/NestJS monorepo powered by NX, and I decided to make better use of NX by organising more stuff into libs, but before I do so, I want to make sure everything is correctly set up so far. The frontend and backend apps share a lib which contains interfaces. They both import from this lib. However, when I run `nx dep-graph`, I just see the frontend, api and shared nodes without any connecting lines between them. What could be the cause of this?

I understand that there may be some context missing in order to be able to correctly analyse the problem, but I don't know exactly what to share, since there is so much relevant code/config, so please let me know what you need, and I'll add it in this question.

Answer (score 3):

Install and then add to your nx.json file this plugin, it should help:

```
{
  "pluginsConfig": {
    "@nrwl/js": {
      "analyzeSourceFiles": true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this works, but seems like it's masking a bug? what do you think?

Comment: I think this is not a bug but rather a choice of developers to have `analyzeSourceFiles` flag in configuration and to set it to false by default

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. A temporary solution I found is to open all modules where you import anything from as a typescript alias. After opening, the graph changes and shows the connection

According to [Nx docs](https://nx.dev/structure/dependency-graph):

> Nx creates a graph of all the dependencies between projects in your workspace using two sources of information:
>
> 1. Typescript import statements referencing a particular project's path alias
> 2. Manually created implicitDependencies in the nx.json file.